# Getting the sum of unique values in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need help creating a formula to sum a few columns of value. But I only want to get the rows with unique texts on the first column (NAME) and the sum of its corresponding column values.

See the table below where I have 8 rows,  but there are only 2 unique values in column C (Angelica Test and Dana DeVito).

| Week | Name | Appointments | Social Media | Texts | Calls | Book | Movement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Angelica Test | 1 | 1 | 5 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Angelica Test | 0 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Dana DeVito | 1 | 1 | 3 | 9 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | Angelica Test | 1 | 1 | 5 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Angelica Test | 0 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | Angelica Test | 1 | 1 | 5 | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | Dana DeVito | 0 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | Angelica Test | 1 | 1 | 4 | 7 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | Angelica Test | 0 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | Dana DeVito | 1 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | Angelica Test | 0 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 1 | 1 |

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KuqthWtbW5A9u_9YaGZgtnA4WX69oQ6DoX3ZmV8645k/edit#gid=898926167

What I want is

- the formula to get the sum of the columns *appointment (F2:F), social media (H2:H), texts (I2:I), calls (J2:J), book (L2:L), and movement (N2:N)* for Angelica Test and Dana DeVito from worksheet named *All responses* to worksheet named *Leaderboard report*.

  (Assuming the formula, the result should be Angelica Test 4, 5, 39, 70, 5, 4 respectively.)
- the same formula with added criteria: the sum of the aforementioned columns for each unique name (column C) of each week.

  (example: sum of *appointment (F2:F), social media (H2:H), texts (I2:I), calls (J2:J), book (L2:L), and movement (N2:N)* for Angelica Test for week 1)

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

**formula in Cell_C2**:

```js
=unique(tocol('All responses'!C2:C,1))
```

**formula in Cell_F2** (`Appointments`):

```js
=map($C2:$C,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,sumif('All responses'!$C:$C,Σ,'All responses'!F:F))))
```

- *You can adjust the `Appointments` formula for other parameters in columns H, I, J, L, N*

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @rockinfreakshow! The formula worked out great. Another question though, what if I add another criteria, say I want the same result for each week (given the responses have a corresponding week in 'All responses' worksheet)?

Comment: then in place of sumif, I'd go with [sumifs()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496) to accommodate the additional conditional week check.

Answer (score 0):

Also with query

```
=query('All Responses'!A1:H,"select B,sum(C),sum(D),sum(E),sum(F),sum(G),sum(H) where B is not null group by B",1)
```

and (to break down by week)

```
=query('All Responses'!A1:H,"select B,A,sum(C),sum(D),sum(E),sum(F),sum(G),sum(H) where B is not null group by B,A",1)
```

[image]